# executing a python(or iron python) script via iron python

Tags: python, ironpython

is this possible? I want to execute a different scriptfile from a iron python script. My main file is getting way to big and I want to make it more readable.

Comment: If your main file is getting too big, organize it. Don't cut it in half and make two files.

Comment: look at the "import" statement and the module system

Comment: it is organized but I think it would be more readable if a ~5000 line block that gets executed quite often was in a different file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you reorganize your script into, say a Python module? Have a look at the [Python Docs about Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

@OP's comment: If you truely have a ~5000 lines of code in a single function you should definitely think about reorganizing your code. If you are sure about that "execute a different script" thing, take a look at [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), although I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: I didn't know about modules before, so I phrased that a bit akwardly. And I already wanted to reorganize it, thats why I asked this question.